# jQuery - open window wing effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am searching for jQuery effect that open div like window with wings. So each wing go to side.

Example:

[image: example]

I tried to search internet but with no luck. Maybe somebody know name of this effect or better a link or technique to achieve such effect.

Thank you for your links / code / suggestions.

Comment: Are you tring a animation? If not, try to create a on click jquery that changes the scr of image

Comment: guess this helps you you..http://thefinishedbox.com/files/tutorials/slidingdoors/index.html

Comment: you should have three separate images then animate using `keyframes` in css3

Answer (score 0):

If you are tring animate here you are a solution

```
<div class="img">
    <img id="imgTest" src="http://thezonemag.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/open-window.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90">
</div>


$(document).on("click", "#imgTest", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      $(this).attr("src","http://i639.photobucket.com/albums/uu112/mich36/Tropical-Breeze.jpg");

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/87bmncex/

Comment: you can create a class "open". Then inside yor code if(!$(this).hasClass("open")){ write your code to open}